# Visual Studio 2017 Compiler Error System.WebExtension not defined

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am attempting to add a subdirectory app to my website but I keep getting a compiler error in Visual Studio 2017 that says the following:

```
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' is defined in an assembly that is not 
 referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0,
```

However, I do reference the assembly System.Web.Extensions in my web.config file.  I don't understand why the compiler doesn't think I reference the System.Web.Extensions assembly.

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
```

So I read somewhere that I have to put in the target Framework in the compilation section of my web.config which I did as shown below:

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="='4.6.1">
```

When I did this I got rid of the above error and it runs ok on my local computer but when I run it on my internet server I get another error:

```
The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework.
```

I know that my website is set up to run under 4.6.1 NetFramework on my server.  So why does it run on my local computer but not my server?   It seems like correcting one error, creates another.      Any suggestions?

Comment: Try copy local = true, it should work.

Comment: I don't understand what copy local=true is.  Where do I put it, in the web.config and what is its syntax?

Comment: Please go to solution explorer > references > right click on 'System.Web.Extensions' chose properties 
 here you can set copy local = true https://imgur.com/a/oVd7rWc

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017. The only way I can get to the references is by right clicking  the project name and then click on Property Pages which shows the assemblies. When I right click on the System.Web.Extension entry, nothing happens.  I tried entering copy local=true in the web.config entry and that created an error.  So do you know how to update the System.Web.Extension using Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: right click on web.extensions and property and set Copy local = true, try again.

Comment: Sorry!  But nothing happens when I right click on web.extensions.  This is so frustrating.  I have been using Visual Studio for 20 years and it seems it becomes more confusing and unworkable with each new release.  I appreciate your help.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: please check this post https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Comment: It seems to me that Visual Studio 2017 does not allow changes to a reference.  All the examples I see are to previous versions of Visual Studio

Comment: Dave, Can you show me the screenshot of properties when you right click of extension and select properties.

Comment: Here is the link to my screen capture.  http://www.minonktalk.com/pics/capturereferences.jpg

Comment: it's look like property of a project, for reference property just right click on xyz.dll and you will see property window, which you have seen earlier by press F4

Comment: Adrian, Thanks for your feedback.  I don't have a Reference tab for my project.  I noticed that it is set up as a website rather than a project.  My systems that are set up as a project have the reference tab under solution explorer while the website systems don't.  I think I will have to set it up as a project to get around this problem.